# command in bash contains printf but the format is not hand over to variable

Tags: bash, format, printf

Bashversion: 4.2.46
OS: linux 3.10.0-1160.108.1.e17

the following command with with printf shall provide three columns with 10 Characters.
Running this only in bash all works fine.

```
$ free -h | grep Mem | awk '{printf "%-10s %-10s %-10slala\n",$2,$3,$4}'
7.6G       2.0G       3.4G       lala
```

Using a variable to do so, the format will  be lost.

```
$ LINE=$(free -h | grep Mem | awk '{printf "%-10s %-10s %-10s\n",$2,$3,$4}')
$ echo $LINE
7.6G 2.0G 3.4G
```

Where go I wrong?

I'm apreciate to get advise from experts

Thank youe

F.

I've tried this so far:

```
$ LINE=$(free -h | grep Mem | awk '{printf "%-10s %-10s %-10s\n",$2,$3,$4}')
$ LINE=`free -h | grep Mem | awk '{printf "%-10s %-10s %-10s\n",$2,$3,$4}'`
$ LINE=${free -h | grep Mem | awk '{printf "%-10s %-10s %-10s\n",$2,$3,$4}'}
```

Comment: Also see [Bash Pitfalls #14 (echo $foo)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies the problem with the code (missing quotes).  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problem and how to fix it.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around `"$LINE"`. Always mind your quotes. `awk` is doing it right, but then you are throwing away the spaces.

```
$ LINE=$(free -h | grep Mem | awk '{printf "%-10s %-10s %-10s\n",$2,$3,$4}')
$ echo $LINE
7.6G 2.0G 3.4G
$ echo "$LINE"
7.6G       2.0G       3.4G
```

(I edited in your memory values from above.)

What are you *doing* with `$LINE`? If you are literally just doing that `printf` then why bother with all the trouble? Just use the command as you showed it... except, *don't*. Try to *never* use multiple regex engines in a single command. Why waste the system resources on a `grep` just to pass the result to `awk` when `awk` can already handle that?

```
$ free -h | awk '/^Mem:/{printf "%-10s%-10s%-10slala\n", $2, $3, $4}'
15G       1.4G      214M      lala
```

Passing the result back to a variable (which you shouldn't generally capitalize, btw) just to pretty-print it out isn't needed unless you are changing the formatting.

If you need those values for other things later, save them and format-print them separately.

```
$ read -r _ totmem usemem fremem _ < <( free -h | grep ^Mem: )
$ printf "total: %-10s used: %-10s free: %s\n" "$totmem" "$usemem" "$fremem"
total: 15G        used: 1.4G       free: 203M
```

or

```
$ read -ra freemem < <( free -m | awk '/^Mem:/{print $2, $3, $4}' )
$ (( ${#freemem[2]}<4 )) && printf "total : %10s\nused  : %10s\nfree  : %10s\n" "${freemem[@]}"
total :      15885
used  :       1434
free  :        225
```

or even

```
$ freemem=( $(free -h) ); printf "%-10s" "${freemem[@]:7:3}"; echo lala
15G       1.4G      217M      lala
```

which probably uses built-in versions of both `printf` and `echo`, so only spawns one subshell for `free`.

I didn't [downvote](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) because it can be hard to figure out how to phrase your search on things like this, but I highly recommend reading the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) and keeping in mind that whitespaces are metacharacters that must be handled accordingly.

Comment: I edited this several times, but it still seems...unnecessarily pompous and snarky to me. Apologies, it isn't intended. Hope it helps.

Comment: I use "$LINE" in a more or less report with further system information. I will do this in a crontab job to get the history of the memory usage for the current day. Unfortunately, I don't know any other way to find the memory consumption of the last 24 hours. Thanks for the help, the tip with the system resources and use only awk command makes totally sense.